# What is the best way to very an IOS auto renewable subscription is active?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

I am looking for some advice on how to go about checking the current status of a users auto renewable subscription.

At the minute I am using the following setup.

1. User registers and subscribes to the product.
2. The receipt is posted to my server.
3. Each night the server pulls all the users where the expiry date is in the past and then using the receipt check to see if the product has been renewed.

Now I think I have an issue with the above setup, it works ok for a small number of people but lets say I have a few thousand. I noticed that calling the Apple servers takes time and so I can't really run the above setup reliably.

I am thinking should I check the receipt locally every time the user opens the app and then post the latest info to my server each time and keep it updated that way? The only issue I have here is that if a user doesn't open for a while then I cant validate their status and my database isn't up to date.

Any advice on the proper approach to take would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a real problem.

At [Elevate](https://www.elevateapp.com/) we would do exactly what you described, checking everyone's receipt every night. This was fine until the time it took to check all of our receipts exceeded 24 hours. At this point we implemented some smart pacing: Each time we checked a receipt and it wasn't subscribed and the user hadn't logged in, we would extend the date where we would check it.

This isn't bullet proof but is a decent balance of accuracy and efficiency.

I thought this was such a crappy problem I [started a company](https://www.revenuecat.com/) to solve it. We do all the nasty receipt checking so you can just ask if a user is active or not.